# Extract information from txt file to CSV

Tags: csv, powershell

My department gets 200-1000 emails every week to go through and remove from one of our Apps. The app will let us use a CSV to "term" the users. I export the emails to txt and am trying to get the info I need to CSV.

Here is my code for the PowerShell:

```
Select-String -Path 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\April22.txt' -Pattern "Account name:", "Name:"
$A = "Name:"; $B = "Account Name:";
$wrapper = New-Object PSObject @{ FirstColumn = $A; SecondColumn = $B }
Export-Csv -InputObject $Wrapper -Path C:\Downloads\Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Here is an example of the txt file information:

```
Account Information:
Name:    something, something    
Account Name:    something   
Email:   something@something.org     
Title:   something   
Department:  something   
Office Location:     something
```

Comment: Please show sample input.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your actual problem is?

Comment: Can not use something like this :
`Import-Csv -Path D:\origtext.txt | Select Account_Name, Name | export-csv selectedcolumncsv.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: The problem is that I when I use my code the only thing I get is it displays the info on the screen followed by an error:  Export-Csv : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
'InputObject'.
At line:4 char:1
+ Export-Csv - InputObject $Wrapper -path C:\Downloads\Test.csv 
-NoTypeInformation
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBind 
   ingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell 
   .Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: So in your code I would replace the (D:\origtext.txt) with my txt file and the (selectedcolumncsv.csv) with my desired csv file? @MilánPintér

Comment: Yes, origtext.txt -> April22.txt and selectedcolumncsv.csv became Test.csv

Comment: when I run it I only get Account_Name in one column and Name in the second Column.

Comment: @MilánPintér I was able to get the information in using something similar to your script:      select-string -Path 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\April22.txt' | Where-Object {$_ -cmatch 'AccountName:|Name:'} | Export-Csv C:\Downloads\Test.csv -NoTypeInformation      Unfortunately it takes some clean up in excel from that point.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks like you posted:

```
Account Information: Name:  LastName, Fristname Account Name: test-person   Account Email:  user@web.org    Title: Info Department: dept-17287  Office Location:    location    Phone Number:   Employee Type:  Ex-employee Employee ID:    1158175 Employee End Date:  2016-04-18 07:00    Manager:    name: test-manager ;
```

You may try something like this:

```
   Get-Content -Path 'C:\a.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $line = $_ -split "`t"
    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Account Name' -Value (($line[2] -split ':')[1]).Trim()
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'name' -Value (($line[-1] -split ':' -replace ';')[1]).Trim()
    $obj
    } | Export-Csv -Path C:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Make sure you changed paths in code and last property **name** indeed have "**:**" in your file.

Comment: This is what I get PSPath PSParentPath PSChildName PSDrive PSProvider ReadCount Length
C:\Users\Public\Documents\April22.txt C:\Users\Public\Documents April22.txt C Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem 5 23
C:\Users\Public\Documents\April22.txt C:\Users\Public\Documents April22.txt C Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem 6 25
C:\Users\Public\Documents\April22.txt C:\Users\Public\Documents April22.txt C Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem 22 25

Comment: Can you post what your file structure is look like? Would be greate if you can comment a couple of rows.

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:9
+         $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Account Name' -Value ( 
...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:5 char:9
+         $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Name' -Value (($line[- 
...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: I edited the coments in the original post to show the real look of the txt file. @AgentK